# Getting error while using the command npm install package_name

Tags: node.js, npm, package, npm-install

I am getting some errors while I am using the command npm install followed any any package name.

The errors that I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Did you read the error message? What did you try about the 'proxy' recommandation?

Comment: I am not using any proxy.

Comment: try to install it in some other directory or restart your terminal or system

Comment: I did but, still facing the error